# Extracting the First (Oldest) Value from Dataset Based on Column Value

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, dataset

I don't have a great deal of experience working with DataSets and haven't been able to find the best way of achieving what I want to achieve.

I basically create a DataSet using a SQL Query and then I am trying to find a Specific Value in the 'Field' column and then if there is a 'Y' in the 'Flag' (as apposed to a 'N') Column on the same Row then I want it to change a check box's state to Checked as well as updating a labels text.

What I have seems to work however if no data is returned I get the below error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I change the code slightly from .FirstOrDefault() to .First()  I get this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

The part of the code that appears to be causing the problem is listed below. If you need to know anything else I will add it in.

```vb
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL =
        <SQL>
            SELECT MAX(UpdateTime) AS UpdateTime FROM AdminCS_Data_Current
            WHERE UpdateUser = |@@UpdateUser|
        </SQL>
    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "@@UpdateUser", AdminCB.Text)
    Me.LastUserUpdate.Text = "Last Action: " & Format(ReturnDatabaseValue(sSQL, "UpdateTime", "Data"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

    Dim EmployeeDataset As New DataSet
    Try
        sSQL =
            <SQL>
                SELECT * FROM AdminCS_Data_Current
                WHERE UpdateUser = |@@UpdateUser| AND CONVERT(DATE, UpdateTime) = CAST(GETDATE() AS  DATE)
                ORDER BY UpdateTime ASC 
            </SQL>
        sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "@@UpdateUser", AdminCB.Text)
        EmployeeDataset = ReturnDataSet(sSQL, "Data")

        If EmployeeDataset IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim eData = EmployeeDataset.Tables(0)
            If (eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()("Flag")) IsNot Nothing Then
                If eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()("Flag").ToString.Trim = "Y" Then
                    TShtY.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                    TShtTime.Text = Format(eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").First()("UpdateTime"), "HH:mm:ss")
                Else
                    TShtN.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                End If
            End If
           ' The above two IF statements would be repeated several times on each change of "Field" 
        End If
```

Comment: The whole point of using `FirstOrDefault` is that there might not be anything in the sequence, so you can't just go ahead and use the result as though there is.  After calling `FirstOrDefault` you must test the result to see whether it's `Nothing` first, then only use it if it's not, i.e. only use the result if it is something.

Comment: If that's not clear enough, think about this.  Let's say that you're entering a room that contains zero, one or more people and I tell you that you can collect $100 from the first person you meet in that room.  If you walk in and there are no people, does $100 magically materialise in your pocket? Of course not, you can only collect the money if there's a person to collect it from.  Likewise, you can only use the first item in a sequence if there is at least one item in that sequence.  `First` requires at least one item while `FirstOrDefault` will return `Nothing` if there are no items.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Isn't that what I have done though? If there is nothing in the sequence surely the IF (IsNot Nothing) wouldn't be entered and it would go straight to the End IF?

Comment: I had a closer look at your code and it's really not good that you're using `eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()` three times.  Surely it's supposed to produce the same result each time so why would you not execute it once, assign the result to a variable and then use that three times?  The fact that it's failing the third time means that the data is being changed in between so you're NOT getting the same result each time.  Your code is not just inefficient as a result but you have introduced a bug.  Don't ever execute the same code over and over like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that this code has introduced not just iunefficiency but also a bug:

```
    If (eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()("Flag")) IsNot Nothing Then
        If eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()("Flag").ToString.Trim = "Y" Then
            TShtY.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            TShtTime.Text = Format(eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").First()("UpdateTime"), "HH:mm:ss")
        Else
            TShtN.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End If
```

It should have been written like this in the first place:

```
    Dim row = eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()

    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        If row("Flag").ToString.Trim = "Y" Then
            TShtY.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
            TShtTime.Text = Format(row("UpdateTime"), "HH:mm:ss")
        Else
            TShtN.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End If
```

Easier to read, more efficient and avoids that nasty bug.

Also, I'd much rather see this:

```
    Dim row = eData.Select("Field = 'Timesheets Checked'").FirstOrDefault()

    If row IsNot Nothing Then
        If row("Flag").ToString.Trim = "Y" Then
            TShtY.Checked = True
            TShtTime.Text = CDate(row("UpdateTime").ToString("HH:mm:ss")
        Else
            TShtN.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
```

You should never use the `CheckState` of a `Checkbox` unless it's tri-state, which maybe yours are but I doubt it.  As for `Format`, we're not in VB6 anymore Toto.